# iOS 9 HTML DOM with position: relative drifts away (floats) from its given position

Tags: css, ios9

There are two distinctive DOM structures in a page. Main content and a Footer. 
CSS:

```
.footer{
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
}

.mainContent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 705px;
    position: relative;
}
```

These two are inside a media query of max width of 1024px.

The problem is that while dragging the main content the main content floats with the gesture.

What is expected is that the main content should be in the same place. This happens only in **iOS 9** and not in iOS 8 or 7!!

Comment: Your css is not valid. Put `;` after each rule. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: A good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You have entertainment while you wait to someone who understand your problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem. Will give debug breakdown and solution as (hopefully) soon.